# Editing image the edited part of image remain unchanged

Tags: python, tkinter, anaconda, opencv

Everyone. I want to ask a question. How to make the edited photo able to change with cv2.trackbar (the bug is the trackbar currently doesn't change the edited photo)?

Here's the full code which I created

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image as PILImage
from PIL import ImageTk
from tkinter import Label
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Menu 
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

effectoption = ["Effect RGB",
"Effect HSV",
"Effect LAB",
"Effect RGBA", "Effect HLS"]

effectoption2 = ["Original(RGB)",
"Original(HSV)",
"Effect3"]

global image, edited

def insertbutton_cb():
    global orima, editima
    
    picpath = filedialog.askopenfilename(
        title="Select An Image", 
        filetypes=(("JPG Files", "*.jpg"), ("GIF Files", "*.gif*"), ("PNG files", "*.png"), ("JPEG Files", "*.jpeg"))
    )
    
    if len(picpath) > 0:
        
        image = cv2.imread(picpath)
        edited = cv2.imread(picpath)
        
        edited = np.array(edited)
        #edited = PILImage.fromarray(edited.astype('uint8'))
        
        print(picpath)
        print('Original Dimensions : ',image.shape)
        print(image)
        print(edited)
        
        scale_percent = 50 # percent of original size
        width = int(image.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
        height = int(image.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
        width2 = int(edited.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
        height2 = int(edited.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
        dim = (width, height)
        dim2 = (width2, height2)
        
        image = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
        edited = cv2.resize(edited, dim2, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
        
        #if effectoption[0] :
            #edited = cv2.cvtColor(edited, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        #elif effectoption[1] :
            #edited = cv2.cvtColor(edited, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        #elif effectoption[2] :
            #edited = cv2.cvtColor(edited, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
        #elif effectoption[3] :
            #edited = cv2.cvtColor(edited, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
        #elif effectoption[4] :
            #edited = cv2.cvtColor(edited, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS)
        
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        edited = cv2.cvtColor(edited, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
        
        image =  PILImage.fromarray(image)
        edited = PILImage.fromarray(edited)
        
        #xa, ya, za = np.shape(image)
        #xb, yb, zb = np.shape(edited)
        
        #image = np.ones((xa, ya, za), np.uint8)
        #edited = np.ones((xb, yb, zb), np.uint8)
        
        image = np.uint8(image)
        edited = np.uint8(edited)
        
        #hueSlider = tk.Scale(Frm2, label="Hue",from_=0, to=100, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=sw, resolution=1, command=huecb)
        #hueSlider.pack(anchor=tk.N)

        #saturationSlider = tk.Scale(Frm2, label="Saturation",from_=0, to=100, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=sw, resolution=1, command=satcb)
        #saturationSlider.pack(anchor=tk.N)

        #brightSlider = tk.Scale(Frm2, label="Brightness",from_=0, to=100, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=sw, resolution=1, command=brightcb)
        #brightSlider.pack(anchor=tk.N)

        #contrastSlider = tk.Scale(Frm2, label="Contrast",from_=0, to=100, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=sw, resolution=1, command=contrastcb)
        #contrastSlider.pack(anchor=tk.N)
        
        bright = 255
        contrast = 100
        saturation = 50
        
        cv2.namedWindow('CV2 Photo Editor')   
        cv2.createTrackbar('Bright', 'CV2 Photo Editor', 255, 2 * 255, bccb)
        cv2.createTrackbar('Contrast', 'CV2 Photo Editor', 255, 2 * 127, bccb)
        cv2.createTrackbar('Saturation', 'CV2 Photo Editor', 255, 2 * 255, bccb) 
        functionbcs(edited, 0, 0, 0)
        bccb(0, 0, 0)
        teste = controller(edited, bright, contrast, saturation)
        cv2.imshow('CV2 Photo Editor', teste)
    
        #cv2.waitKey(0)
        
    if orima is None or editima is None:
        orima = Label(image=image)
        orima.image = image
        orima.pack(side="left", padx= 0, pady=0)
        
        editima = Label(image=edited)
        editima.image = edited
        editima.pack(side="right", padx= 0, pady=0)
    else:
        orima.configure(image=image)
        editima.configure(image=edited)
        orima.image = image
        editima.image = edited

def resetbutton_cb():
    orima = None
    editima = None

def savebutton_cb():
    pass

def functionbcs(edited, bright=0, contrast=0, saturation=0):
        
    #edited = cv2.cvtColor(edited, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    bright = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Bright','CV2 Photo Editor')
    contrast = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Contrast','CV2 Photo Editor')
    saturation = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Saturation','CV2 Photo Editor')
    edited = controller(edited, bright, contrast, saturation)
    #print("Edited : " + edited)
    print(edited)
    cv2.imshow("Edited", edited)

def satcb(satpos = 0):
    print(satpos)

def bccb(bright = 0, contrast=0, saturation=0):
    print("B : " + str(bright))
    bright = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Bright', 'CV2 Photo Editor')
    print("C :" + str(contrast))
    contrast = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Contrast', 'CV2 Photo Editor')
    print("S :" + str(saturation))
    saturation = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Saturation', 'CV2 Photo Editor')
    
    
def controller(effect, bright=1, contrast=1, saturation=1):
    bright = int((bright - 0) * (255 - (-255)) / (510 - 0) + (-255))
  
    contrast = int((contrast - 0) * (127 - (-127)) / (254 - 0) + (-127))
    
    saturation = int((saturation - 0) * (100 - (-100)) / (200 - 0) + (-100))
    
    if bright != 0:
        if bright > 0:
            shadow = bright
            max = 255
        else:
            shadow = 0
            max = 255 + bright
        alf = (max - shadow) / 255
        gam = shadow
        
        cal = cv2.addWeighted(edited, alfa, 
                              edited, 0, gam)
    else:
        cal = effect
    
    if contrast != 0:
        Alf2 = float(131 * (contrast + 127)) / (127 * (131 - contrast))
        Gam2 = 127 * (1 - Alf2)
  
        # The function addWeighted calculates
        # the weighted sum of two arrays
        cal = cv2.addWeighted(cal, Alf2,
                              cal, 0, Gam2)
    cv2.putText(cal, 'B:{},C:{}, S:{}'.format(bright,
                                        contrast, saturation), (10, 30),
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
    cv2.imshow('CV2 Photo Editor', effect)
    
    return cal
    

def exitbutton_cb():
    window.destroy()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Simple Photo Editing')
mb = Menu(window)
#file manager
fm = Menu(mb, tearoff=0)
fm.add_command(label="Open", command=insertbutton_cb)
fm.add_command(label="Save", command=savebutton_cb)
fm.add_separator()
#fm.add_command(label="Cancel Edit", command=pass)
fm.add_command(label="Exit", command=exitbutton_cb)
mb.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fm)

var1 = tk.StringVar(window)
var1.set(effectoption[0])

cr = ttk.Frame(window)
canvas = tk.Canvas(cr)
scrolling = ttk.Scrollbar(cr, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)

sw = window.winfo_screenwidth()
sh = window.winfo_screenheight()

Frm = tk.Frame(window, height=50, width=300)
Frm.pack(anchor=tk.N)

Frm2 = tk.Frame(window, height=25, width=100)
Frm2.pack(anchor=tk.NW)

#Frm3 = tk.Frame(window, height=50, width=500)
#Frm3.pack(anchor=tk.N)

#showWin = tk.Label(window, width=100, height=100)
#showWin.pack(side='left')

#showWin2 = tk.Label(window, width=100, height=100)
#showWin2.pack(side='left')

label = ttk.Label(
    window, text="Simple Image Photo Editing"
)

resetbutton = tk.Button(Frm, text="Reset", padx=0, pady=0, command=resetbutton_cb)
resetbutton.grid(row=0, column=1)

savebutton = tk.Button(Frm, text="Save", padx=0, pady=0, command=savebutton_cb)
savebutton.grid(row=0, column=2)

orima = None
editima = None

opt = tk.OptionMenu(window, var1, *effectoption)
opt.config(width=90, font=('Helvetica', 12))
opt.pack(side="top")

print(opt)

window.config(menu=mb)
cv2.waitKey(0)
tk.mainloop()
```

When I tried to apply the photo with cv2 slider, the edited image remain unchanged and the value despite the trackbar can slide normally but still won't change for the photo

Comment: You did not apply the values changed and update the image inside `bccb()` function.

Comment: Can you share the code for clearer and more detail about the answer?

Comment: Actually `functionbcs()` is what you need for `bccb()` except that you should apply `controller()` on the original image, not the edited image.

Comment: I replace the edited with original part but the trackbar still won't apply it. I suggest to you write the full code on answer that would be more clear to know and give more detail.

Comment: The code in [here](https://pastebin.com/dV1zYzeL) is a modified version of yours that you can reference.

Comment: Well thank you for help for change the effect. Anyway, i still find to change saturation and effectoption(which i commented with "#") function for image since i want to implement different RGB, HSV and RGBA

Comment: Actually I didn't fully understand your code, so the code in the link is just a reference example.  The others are on your own.